# ListCollectionView's live shaping bug

Tags: wpf, sorting, dynamic

After digging deeper, why live shaping, in detail the automatic sorting of groups by name, is not working, I decided to wrote a small test application, solution download is here:

[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwhjfti46a06dmq/LiveShapingTest.zip?dl=0)

Following, a description of the problem: I use an ObservableCollection of Person objects, with Age and Name properties (with NPC). I create a ListCollectionView bound to a  DataGrid with a custom GroupStyle to expose an Expander

For this view I set:

- GroupDescription to Age
- SortDescription to Age (to sort the groups)
- SortDescription to Name

After start a DispatcherTimer recalculates all Ages of each Person to a random value between 30 and 45.

At runtime the fault: for about 60-70% of all dynamic resorts of the groups, the sorting order is right e.g. for example 31 before 34 before 41 before 45. But sometimes a 30th number is between two 40th numbers, and that's wrong. Where is the problem and how can I solve? By the way, the problem only occures for group ordering.

BTW: For what purpose is the LiveSortingProperties collection, setting a  SortDescription and IsLiveSorting=True obviously activates live shaping, In which situation I should add a string to this collection?

Here is a screenshot of the wrong group sorting:

[Example Picture of wrong sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D4TY.png):

[image]

Comment: I have added a bug entry at Microsoft connect. Maybe you might vote it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2017716/wpf-live-shaping-groups-are-not-sorted-correctly-after-a-property-changes

Comment: Thank you, jbe. Do you encountered this problem as well?

Answer (score 1):

Groups are presented in order of discovery.   In your case the data is sorted by Age (then by Name), so the initial scan of the data will discover the Age-31 group before the Age-34 group.  However if none of the people have Age=37, there is no Age-37 group.   Later on, if add a new Person (or change the Age of an existing Person, when Live-Grouping is enabled) with Age=37, a new Age-37 group is created.   But since it is discovered after the initial groups, it gets added after all those groups.

At present (4.6.1) there is no way to declare a sort order for the groups themselves.   We are considering adding this feature, as many people ask for it.

BTW: The purpose of LiveSortingProperties is for cases when you want to sort by properties A, B, and C, but you know that only property C will change.  Declare all three properties in SortDescriptions, but declare only C in LiveSortingProperties.   That way we won't waste effort setting up change listeners for A and B that would never be called.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem as well. Because my client's may not immediately upgrade to 4.6.2 I created a work around.

My application uses ReactiveUI (http://reactiveui.net/) which facilitates this solution. Adapting my solution to your Person example, basically I monitor any changes to the Age property, then count the number of groups (i.e. Ages) and only when the number of age groups change (DistinctUntilChanged) do I reconfigure the grouping and sorting.

Because this uses a reactive pattern it is pretty efficient, but also in my case there are only a few dozen elements at any one time.

```
// NB People is a ReactiveList<Person>

void SetupInterface()
{
    People.ItemChanged.Select(p => p.PropertyName == "Age")
        .Where(ageChanged => ageChanged)
        .DistinctUntilChanged(_ => People.GroupBy(x => x.Age).Count())
        .Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            ConfigureGrouping();
        });
    ConfigureGrouping();
}

void ConfigureGrouping()
{
    using (_collectionView.DeferRefresh())
    {
        // code to reset and rebuild the group and sort descriptions...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
 timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000);
 timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
 {
      foreach (var person in Persons)
      {
           person.Age = rnd.Next(30, 45);
       }
       PersonsView.Refresh();
  };
  timer.IsEnabled = true;
```

View.Refresh did the trick for me

Comment: Ok, that's seems to be a solution, but not very satisfying as 'live shaping' should work out of the box. And in my special case (changing a property that is responsible for a group creation and sorting of this group), I don't have a reference to the view itself. I could use some events, but that's not clean for me. Anyway, what is the description for this "bug"?

Comment: why you did not have a reference to your IcollectionView? its in your viewmodel so you have this reference for sure and you can call .Refresh when ever you need to

Comment: because, in my example, the code that modifies the sorting property is in the same location like the view itself, this is just for demonstration. originally, the change will come from another assembly just setting the value but without knowing the view. IMO, it should work and it's obviously a framework bug

Comment: the object in the other assembly have to implement INPC at least. so you could listen to PropertyChanged too and call refresh

Comment: It already implements INPC, I guess this is the requirement to get the live shaping working ;) I only found it tedious to attach/detach listener to each object during runtime.